# Exiting out of a smart contract early?

Tags: contract-development, ether

Basically i want to have a smart contract that can allow users to exit early under specific conditions. Does anyone have any resources for this or know whether its possible?

Comment: Exit what? It's not clear what you mean by that, or what, precisely needs to happen when the user exits.

Comment: Apologies, lets say person A puts money into a smart contract that is time locked for 1 year. Person A then has to pay rent in the real world and needs to exit out from the smart contract early to release their funds to pay for their rent. For what i want to do its important that person A have the option to exit out whenever they wish.

Simply wishing to know if this would be possible within smart contracts?

Comment: yes it's possible tp write such contract, as you describe it. you can define an exit function that can refund you before the deadline.